# How do i visualize a connection Matrix with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, visualization

I am trying to visualize a connection matrix of an bi-partite set problem. How do i do this in a way that demonstrates best?

I have started with this using a graphics program yed:

[image: example]

The circles describe a certain kind of connection between red and blue and the squares another. Both red and blue squares will have some kind of text on them.

However it would be nicer to generate this grafic with matplotlib, since i would like to generate this on the fly with data attached. How would i proceed to do that?
My data looks kinda like this:

Data:

```
name_blue name_red Connection Type
bluepart1 redpart1 1
bluepart1 redpart2 1
bluepart1 redpart3 1
bluepart3 redpart2 2 
bluepart4 redpart2 2
...
```

and so on. I would like to write the nametags onto the blue/red squares, so that the user knows which is which.

Followup question: 
How can i generate a graph from this with the nodes partly marked blue/red? Kind of like this:

[image: graphexample]

But with the nodes reflecting their bipartite nature. I am still a bit in the dark on this, mainly because i don't know how to tackle this with matplotlib. I am hoping for a few good suggestions on how to visualize this and maybe an example implementation that shows me the way.

Comment: You should split your follow up question into a separate question.

Comment: whazt i tried is pasting pictures in a grid of n^2 subplots. However this is not really pythonic or the matplotlib way of doing this. A better solution for me and other people who need this kind of visualization would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing a bipartite representation with color edges like this?

[image: Bipartite graph with different kinds of connections]

Following is the code that generated the image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def addconnection(i,j,c):
  return [((-1,1),(i-1,j-1),c)]

def drawnodes(s,i):
  global ax
  if(i==1):
    color='r'
    posx=1
  else:
    color='b'
    posx=-1

  posy=0
  for n in s:
    plt.gca().add_patch( plt.Circle((posx,posy),radius=0.05,fc=color))
    if posx==1:
      ax.annotate(n,xy=(posx,posy+0.1))
    else:
      ax.annotate(n,xy=(posx-len(n)*0.1,posy+0.1))
    posy+=1

ax=plt.figure().add_subplot(111)
set1=['Man1','Man2','Man3','Man4']
set2=['Woman1','Woman2','Woman3','Woman4','Woman5']
plt.axis([-2,2,-1,max(len(set1),len(set2))+1])
frame=plt.gca()
frame.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
frame.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])

drawnodes(set1,1)
drawnodes(set2,2)

connections=[]
connections+=addconnection(1,2,'g')
connections+=addconnection(1,3,'y')
connections+=addconnection(1,4,'g')
connections+=addconnection(2,1,'g')
connections+=addconnection(4,1,'y')
connections+=addconnection(4,3,'g')
connections+=addconnection(5,4,'y')

for c in connections:
  plt.plot(c[0],c[1],c[2])

plt.show()
```

To get something like what your are drawing in yEd

[image: Connection matrix]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

COLOR1='r'
COLOR2='b'

def addconnection(i,j,c):
  if(c==1):
    plt.gca().add_patch( plt.Rectangle((j-0.1,-i-0.1),0.2,0.2,fc='y'))
  if(c==2):
    plt.gca().add_patch( plt.Circle((j,-i),radius=0.1,fc='y'))

def drawnodes(s,i):
  global ax
  if(i==1):
    color=COLOR1
    vx=1
    vy=0
  else:
    color=COLOR2
    vx=0
    vy=1

  step=1
  for n in s:
    posx=step*vx
    posy=step*vy

    plt.gca().add_patch( plt.Circle((posx,-posy),radius=0.1,fc=color))
    ax.annotate(n,xy=(posx-len(n)*0.1,-posy+0.15))
    step+=1

f=open('input.txt')
t=f.readlines()
t=map(lambda x: x.replace('(',' ').replace(')',' ').split(':'),t)

set1=set([])
set2=set([])

for x in t:
  s=x[1].split()
  set1.add(s[0])
  set2.add(s[1])

set1=list(set1)
set2=list(set2)

dic={}
for e in zip(set1,xrange(1,len(set1)+1)): dic[(e[0],1)]=e[1]
for e in zip(set2,xrange(1,len(set2)+1)): dic[(e[0],2)]=e[1]

ax=plt.figure(figsize=(max(len(set1),len(set2))+1,max(len(set1),len(set2))+1)).add_subplot(111)
plt.axis([-1,max(len(set1),len(set2))+1,-max(len(set1),len(set2))-1,1])
frame=plt.gca()
frame.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
frame.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])

drawnodes(set1,1)
drawnodes(set2,2)

for x in t:
  s=x[1].split()
  addconnection(dic[(s[0],1)],dic[(s[1],2)],int(x[2]))

plt.show()
```

Comment: would accept, if the connection matrix were also in there ... :)

Comment: @tarrasch oh, I understand. I'm not sure a clean graph representation is possible, except if you know the sets are small because you're going to have to draw multiple cliques interconnected. I drew with matplotlib exactly what you made with yEd, which I think shows best this information and modified the answer with the code

Comment: ok, you earned this :) i'll additionally upvote you if you can recognize my file format and convert it: "Pair :(MAN  DESC WOMAN   DESC) type:1" Where MAN DESC is the name of the node. I have a whole file of this manner.

Comment: @tarrasch sure, I assumed your descriptions won't contain spaces or ':' for simplicity

Answer (score 7):

Try using [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/). You can use it to display the graph with specific colors on the nodes and links to match your data.

Here's an example:

```
import itertools
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
edgelist = [(u,v,(u+v)%2) for u,v in itertools.product(range(3),range(3,6))]
G = nx.Graph()
for u,v,t in edgelist:
    G.add_edge(u,v,attr_dict={'t':t})
ecolors = tuple('g' if G[u][v]['t'] == 1 else 'm' for u,v in G.edges())
nx.draw_networkx(G,node_color='rrrccc',edge_color=ecolors)
plt.show()
```

[image: Simple Example]

Comment: will definitely check that out.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another NetworkX/Matplotlib idea

```
import random
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.bipartite import biadjacency_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# generate random bipartite graph, part 1: nodes 0-9, part 2: nodes 10-29
B = nx.bipartite_random_graph(10,20,0.25)
# add some random weights
for u,v in B.edges():
    B[u][v]['weight']=random.randint(0,4)

# spring graphy layout
plt.figure(1)
pos = nx.spring_layout(B)
colors = [d['weight'] for (u,v,d) in B.edges(data=True)]
nx.draw(B,pos,node_color='#A0CBE2',edge_color=colors,width=4,edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues,with_labels=False)
plt.savefig('one.png')

# simple bipartite layout
plt.figure(2)
pos = {}
for n in range(10):
    pos[n]=(n*2,1)
for n in range(10,30):
    pos[n]=(n-10,0)
nx.draw(B,pos,node_color='#A0CBE2',edge_color=colors,width=4,edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues,with_labels=False)
plt.savefig('two.png')

# biadjacency matrix colormap
M = biadjacency_matrix(B,row_order=range(10),column_order=range(10,30))
plt.matshow(M,cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.savefig('three.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]